# print the total number of ways that you can climb the stairs by recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I WANT to write code that prints the total number of ways that you can climb the stairs using one step, two steps at a time, or three steps at a time.

my code is

```
public static int math(int n ){


        if (n==0){
            return 0;

        }
        else if (n==1){
       return 1;

        }    
        else return math(n-1)+math(n-2);
    }
```

but my code it does not give me the correct output.
Is there another way?

Comment: How does that code take into account 3 steps at a time?

Comment: isnt that just a fibonacci algorithm

Comment: @redFIVE what is fibonacci algorithm

Comment: What should be the output if n is equal to 3?

Comment: for n = 3 is answer 4? like, 1+1+1, 1+2, 2+1, 3

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your base case doesn't make sense. If there are 0 steps left, there is only one way to climb. Your base case says if there are 0 ways there are 0 ways to climb.

Also, you don't need an else statement in this case to call the recursive case. The method should get there if the return statements haven't been called at the top.

```
int climb(int a){       
   if(a <= 2)          
       return a;       
   return climb(a-1)+climb(a-2);
}
```

This is the code for 2 steps at a time. You figure out the 3 steps at a time code...

Comment: I have trial your code but when input 3 the output 3 but the correct answer 4 !

Comment: because you're still only taking 1 or 2 steps at a time. never 3 steps. given 3 steps, you can take them as '1-1-1' (one step at a time) or '2-1' or '1-2' (2 steps then one, or vice versa) thats three possible ways to walk the stairs. now, try to modify the solution to add walking 3 steps at a time.

Comment: Yes, my solution only accounts for 1 or 2 steps at at time.

Comment: @jb. The method take one number how take 3 steps at time

Comment: @user4746449, You tell me :) I'll gladly offer hints, but you'll learn more if you try to figure it out yourself. Which part are you getting stuck on? first hint: which part of Kai's code is accounting for taking steps 1 and 2 at a time?

Comment: return climb(a-1)+climb(a-2);  in this case ?

Comment: yep!  `a` is your total number of steps left to climb, right? so that code says 'tell me how many ways i can climb, if i take 1 step right now, and also tell me how many ways i can climb if i take 2 steps right now and i'll add those two numbers together'. Now, modify it for taking 3 steps too.

Comment: @jb. if i take 1 step right now =1 ways ..  and if i take 2step right now = 2 ways , true?

Comment: climb(1) should return 1 (just '1'), climb(2) should return 2 ('1-1' or '2'). is that what you're asking?

Comment: @jb. What about climb 3 ?

Comment: it depends, with climbing 3 steps at a time or not? with it, it is: climb(3) == ('1-1-1', '1-2', '2-1', '3') == 4